# Тег <template> во vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Для чего используется тег `<template>` во vuejs? Я часто его вижу в коде, но назначения так и не понял.

Comment: не знаю как во vue, а так вообще это часть html-спеки https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

Comment: они не рендерятся, но их можно клонировать